# I'm aiming to develop for multiple platforms - should I use Java SE or ME?

Tags: java, android, iphone, blackberry, java-me

I'm planning to develop a library that will work on multiple platforms: Android, BlackBerry, Windows, MacOS.

I will probably use a lot of functionality having to do with XML parsing and HTTP requests and responses.

Should I be aiming for Java SE or ME during development?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Although it not used on some of today's newest mobile platforms (e.g. iPhone, Windows Phone 7, BlackBerry's new QNX, Android), it continues to be very popular in sub $200 devices such as Nokia's Series 40. It is also used on new Bada operating system and on Symbian OS along with native software."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have no choice like "SE vs ME", really

- Android is Android. It's Java SE (almost), but it cannot call itself Java SE nor Java ME
- BlackBerry is Java ME
- Windows and Mac OS run Java SE, there's no point to run Java ME there
- Windows phones run neither. OK, you can run Java ME, but users won't

So the answer will be, "both and don't forget Android"

Comment: The last bit: iOS doesn't run Java either. As for BlackBerry, they also have extra libraries (depending on OS version), see http://us.blackberry.com/developers/blackberry7. Dalvik (Android) is similar enough to SE that for a library (i.e. no gui) you should not have many compatibility problems.

Comment: @Viruzzo true. iOS wasn't mentioned, so I skipped it. All good points nevertheless.

Comment: Considering Android can run nearly any Java library out of github, it seems overly pedantic to say it is not Java SE.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: Also, how do you plan to run Java ME on a Windows Phone?  users won't because they can't.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue I mean, Android can't be Java due to the suit with Oracle. Consider it a poor joke. I wouldn't be so optimistic about "nearly any Java library out of github," though.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue my colleagues did use Java ME compatible runtime on a Windows phone. It takes a lot of work, but it works for them. No user in his own mind would do that. I personally did not try, but I have a nice J2ME app runner for Android—it works wonders. Again, useless for anything but PoC.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.   I see what you're saying now.

Comment: @alf I'd say Android is one of the last remaining big Java applications, if not the last. And agree with you on the github thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for developing applications in Java ME, I suggested [Use LWUIT.](http://lwuit.java.net/) Its supports [Java ME, Blackberry and Android.](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html) You have change little bit on each platform. No need to change full source code. Look on following useful links,

- [LWUIT blog](http://www.lwuit.com/)
- [About LWUIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152237/what-is-lwuit-light-weight-user-interface-toolkit)

**Note:** In future [LWUIT supports iPhone.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qvcZOIWSF4) :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm building just a library. There's no need for a user interface.